sign an instruction on the frontend, another on the backend for the same transaction

i have a few questions:
whats the best way to handle this
do i create the txn on the backend, then let the frontend sign and send it? if so how?
how can i partially sign the transaction on the backend, send the base58 encoded string to the frontend, and create the transaction again on the frontend, sign it and send it
any code snippets would help

You have to first use the @solana/web3.js library to create a transaction in backend, add appropriate instructions, sign it if needed using local keypair, then encode it in base58/base64, send it to frontend, then frontend will load the base58/base64 string into a Transaction object, and then sign it and send it. Here is how you can achieve this:
First, create a backend transaction creation handler API, something like this:
export const createTx = async () => {
  let tx = new Transaction();
  // Add instructions

  const { blockhash } = await new Connection("rpc").getLatestBlockhash();

  const kp = Keypair.fromSecretKey("your_secret"key); // If you need backend sign, loading local kp and sign tx

  tx.recentBlockhash = blockhash;

  const serialized = tx.serialize({ requireAllSignatures: false });
  return {"transaction": bs58.encode(serialized)} // API response
};

Now, make a call to this API, which will return your encoded transaction. In your frontend, you have to load it and request signing it now, here is how:
const res = await fetch("api_url")
const data = await res.json()

const tx = Transaction.from(base58.decode(data.transaction))  
tx.feePayer = wallet.publicKey

signedTx = await wallet.sign(tx)
const txSignature = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, tx);

